# How do I define the attaching map from $S^1$ to $S^1 \vee S^1\ $?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I came across the fact the torus i.e. $S^1 \times S^1$ has the structure of a CW-complex. To see that we need to start with the $0$-skeleton $X^0$ consisting of a single point $*.$ Then we attach two $1$-cells to $X^0$ via the obvious attaching map $* \bigsqcup *$ from $S^0 \bigsqcup S^0$ to $X^0.$ With this attachment map the pushout we obtain is the $1$-skeleton $X^1$ which is the wedge of two circles $S^1 \vee S^1.$ At last we need to to attach a single $2$-cell to $X^1$ to get a torus. But here it is not known to me that what would be the attaching map from $S^1$ to $S^1 \vee S^1.$ Do anybody have any idea about that? A small hint will be highly appreciated at this stage.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Visualize the torus as the square with opposite edges identified. You may view the  interior of the square as the 2-cell, so that the attaching map is via the word $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. where $a, b$ represent the circles of $S^1\vee S^1$.

Comment: @Mysterium ok that's I understand. But my question is $:$ how do I transform this visualization into a function from $S^1$ to $S^1 \vee S^1\ $? My idea is to first transform $S^1$ homeomorphically onto the boundary of the unit square. Then we identify each pair of opposite edges with the generating circles of $S^1 \vee S^1.$ What I intuitively feel is that this identification leads us to the structure of a torus. But how does that map horizontal and vertical pairs of lines of the boundary of the unit square to the generating circles is not quite clear to me? Can you shed some light on it?

Comment: let's use $I\times I$ to represent the square, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,0)$ (four edges) are all identified, which makes each edge a circle, and pairs of opposite edges are also identified meaning that there are two circles that are joined at one point. This is the $S^1\vee S^1$. By attaching the boundary of the disk via $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, boundary circle of the cell traverse once on the circle $a$, and then $b$ (goes back to the joining point), and then traverse in the opposite direction. Hope it's clearer.

Comment: @Mysterium I get your point. But what's the underlying function that takes points of $S^1$ to points of $S^1 \vee S^1\ $?

Comment: It seems that you want to explicitly define the map, unfortunately I can't write down the expression, it's not on the top of my head. To actually write down the map, you probably need some coordinate geometry but that's not easy and not useful because I can continuously deform the circle so that the map will dramatically change. Normally, the word $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ is sufficient to convey the idea, and that is what the attaching map usually appears in the discussion of cell complex, especially when computing fundamental groups, see Hatcher proposition 1.26.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate $S^1$ in four arcs call them $p_1p_2,p_2p_3,p_3p_4,p_4p_1$ and direction is clockwise and identify $D^2$ as $I^2$ , mark this square square as ABCD in an anticlockwise direction starting from left.
Let us also call the two circles of $S^1\vee S^1$ by $a,b$ with appropriate direction (think them as a directed path).
Now you map the arc $\overrightarrow{p_1p_2}$
to side $\overrightarrow{AB}$ of the square , the arc $\overrightarrow{p_2p_3}$
to side $\overrightarrow{BC}$ of the square and so on.
Now, we give the identification map as follows, map the arc $\overrightarrow{p_1p_2}$ to the directed loop $a$ then the arc $\overrightarrow{p_2p_3}$ to the directed loop $b$ , then the arc $\overrightarrow{p_3p_4}$ to the directed loop $a^{-1}$ (i.e. now traverse in the opposite direction) and finally the arc $\overrightarrow{p_4p_1}$ to the directed loop $b^{-1}$  and this gives you the torus as the initial object of the pushout diagram

Comment: Really clear explanation. This is essentially what I said in the comment, but the author's follow-up question is somehow confusing because he/she wants to know the "underlying function", and I'm not sure if this is what the author wants, but anyway, your answer is very clear.

Comment: Why do you take different orientations to circle and square? I think that if you homeomorphically deform a circle to a square by matching the vertices (i.e. the initial and endpoints of the arcs of the circle respectively map to the initial and endpoints of the line segments of the boundary of the square) then the orientation will get reversed. Am I right @S Dey?

Comment: You can take same orientation that doesn't matter.Btw, I am not S Dey. I am Dey.

Comment: That was a typo. Since I have turned on prediction in my phone it got predicted in that way what I have overlooked. I think that this is happening due to the fact that I have sent several messages addressing to one of my close friends whose name happens to be S Dey. For your kind information let me tell you that "Dey" is a very common surname in the Bengali community to which I am a part of. Please don't mind. Extremely sorry for that.